# How to display spinner or progress bar while image loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-image

I am making the react, next.js app on which I am displaying various images:
[image]

The user is clicking on the item from the list on the left, and it's getting three images on the right. The images are displaied based on next.js Image component:

```
            <Image
          src={visualizationData[0]}
          quality={50}
          alt="Zdjęcie oryginalne"
          width={600}
          height={600}
        />
```

Where `visualizationData` is a variable using the State Hook and returing 3 urls to photos that user wants to display:

```
const [visualizationData, setVisualizationData] = useState(getVisualizationData(props.history.model.name, props.history.dataLists[0].replace('img/', '')));
```

So it returns something like this:
[image]

Everything is working fine, but slow, because backend needs to convert .tif photos to .jpg and it takes like 3 seconds. I want to display for this 3 seconds a [spinner](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/) or something similar to spinner instead of leaving the user with the old visualizations.

How to make it? I don't know how to check that photo is loaded or not, because I am only passing urls to the `src` prop of the Image component.

Here is a code of `getVisualizationData(modelName, pathAndPhotoName)`:

```
    export function getVisualizationData(modelName, pathAndPhotoName) {
  const photoName = pathAndPhotoName.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
  const datasetPath = pathAndPhotoName.replace(`/${photoName}`, '');
  const visualizationData = [
    `${backendUrl}download/datasets/${datasetPath}/image/${photoName}`,
    `${backendUrl}download/datasets/${datasetPath}/mask/${photoName}`,
    `${backendUrl}download/models/${modelName}/Predictions/1/${photoName}`];
  return visualizationData;
}
```

It is converting the path to the photos and returning it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a isLoading boolean. If isLoading is true, then show the Spinner. If not, then the data has been fetched and you can stop showing the spinner and start showing the pictures.

Please notice I don't have enough information about what getVisualizationData returns exactly. But basically, it should return a Promise resolved with the value fetched. So look at this code, get the idea and apply it.

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
 
      const result = await getVisualizationData(props.history.model.name, props.history.dataLists[0].replace('img/', '')); //Please check this line    
      setVisualizationData(result);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Then in your component, you can render a spinner while isLoading is true. When it's false, then you render what you want to show:

```
return(
{isLoading ? (
        <SpinnerComponent />
      ) : (
        <div>
          //Render here your pictures
        </div>
      )}
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but getVisualizationData is not even an async function - it is only converting path to photos to url endpoint - so will be your solution working? I added getVisualization() method code to the question, could you check it?